# binding with mathematic operation in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have three `TextBox`es: `WBC_txt`, `NE_txt` and `result_txt`.

I want to do this operation with binding:

```
(WBC_txt.text * NE_txt.text) * 10
```

and show the result in `result_txt.Text`.

I've tried the `ElementName` and `Path` way but it didn't work because it serves only one value.

What is the best way to do it with XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option to putting an explicit property Result in your ViewModel is to make a Multiconverter

If you don't reference Result anywhere else in your ViewModel this might be the best way to go since it will allow you to reuse this mathematical operation & not worry about Result's property being updated.

This will look something like

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="Result">
    <TextBox.Text>
        // OneWay binding necessary in this case otherwise it will 
        // try calling ConvertBack which is NotSupported
        <Multibinding Converter="{StaticResource WPCandNEtoResultConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding Path="Wbc">
            <Binding Path="Ne">
        </Multibinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**C# IMultiValueConverter**

```
public class WPCandNEtoResultConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var wbc = values[0];
        var ne = values[1];

        return return wbc * ne * 10;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create three properties is Viewmodel, two that represent the content of `WBC_txt` and `NE_txt` through data-binding, and a third one that returns the calculation result:

```
private double _wbc;
public double Wbc
{
    get { return _wbc; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _wbc)
        {
            _wbc = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Wbc");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Result");
        }
    }
}

private double _ne;
public double Ne
{
    get { return _ne; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _ne)
        {
            _ne = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Ne");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Result");
        }
    }
}

public double Result
{
    get { return Wbc * Ne * 10; }
}
```

Then bind this third property `Result` to the result_txt textbox!

Comment: Don't forget to call NotifyPropertyChanged("Result") in the setters for Ne & Wbc.

Comment: thanks but i need to do this by XAML maybe by using binding parameters and value converter but i dont know how to do it..thanks

Comment: if you really need to get it done without a Viewmodel involved, @William Thomas Waller's solution should work for you...